# Some problems with the confirmation of the urls in Django views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

**My models:**

Story:

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Category: name | slug

**My urls:**

```
(r'^(?P<cat_slug>.*)/$', 'news.views.archive_category'),
```

And in **views**, I use:

```
def archive_category(request, cat_slug):
    entry = News.objects.get( categories__slug=cat_slug )
    return render_to_response('news_archive_category.html', {'entry':entry, })
```

It has something wrong if I have a story of two or more category. Please help me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
category = Category.objects.filter(slug=cat_slug)#get the category requested
#now get all the entries which have that category
entries = News.objects.filter(categories__in=category)#because of the many2many use __in
```

**edited after comment**

Comment: Thank you. But if we do this will be generated error: 'Category' object is not iterable.

Comment: my bad. use filter instead of get. then there is no need for the try/except. the queryset is iterable.

Comment: no need for the try/except error-wise, but you may want to do something to catch if there are no entries. on my multiblog i just leave it alone and display the requested page with no entries.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to happen in this circumstance? Are you trying to show a list of all the entries in a category, or just one?

`News.objects.get()` will *always* get a single item, or raise an exception if there are more than one matching the criteria. Either you should use `filter()` instead, passing a QuerySet to the template, so you'll need to iterate through; or, add a criteria to your urlconf so that you get the specific entry slug as well, so you only get one object.

Comment: Use the filter is the options simpler.